# Complete hard disk format

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, hard-drive

I was earlier using windows 7 on my pc. But I then think of switching to Ubuntu  14.04. I downloaded the iso and choose the complete clean and install option. The Ubuntu doesn't install due to some issues of harddisk. Now my pc is not having any OS.
I request you all to please help me in this regards.
I want to completely erase my hard disk and want to install Ubuntu.

Comment: "some issues" can usually fixed by "some solutions". Can you please add a little more detail? And what do you want to achieve? (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 1):

Boot from your installation media, use the 'try Ubuntu now' option & check it runs on your PC OK. Then re-try with the install option from the desktop.

If it doesn't come up on the 'try it now' option then ask another question - unless you can find an existing answer to whatever does happen...

Comment: While installing, after copying files step the installing system step is taking a long time more than 2hrs. And after that too the system is not powering ON on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

> First of all don't worry.Make the ubuntu file burn into a cd or you can choose installing using your pendrive(after making it bootable).

It's the  easy method.And since you don't have any OS installed you have to download and burn it in someone else's computer.
It will be approximately 1GB.
After that reinstall Ubuntu.And it is the second option to completely clean and install.Make sure you select that.After that just follow the on-screen instructions and you are good to go then.

Comment: He already has the ISO in some form, having been through the install process once...

Comment: While installing, after copying files step the installing system step is taking a long time more than 2hrs. And after that too the system is not powering ON on Ubuntu.